# toFixed() causing an error with useState hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tofixed

In just making a static single-item purchasing modal, I've encountered a curious bug between the toFixed() and useState(). I wrote a basic changeQuantity(dir) function using a switch/case statement and when I try to use toFixed(2) on a tempTotal variable, I get an error telling me my useState (setQuantity) is now not a function?? The consequence is trivial and there's no issue just calling toFixed() on {total} in the UI, but I am curious as to whats causing it.

While I could see why using `toFixed` inside the `setTotal()` hook could cause fuss, I certainly wasn't expecting any lip out of setQuantity, so I'm curious how the hook seems to be overrode/not recognized?? Again, mainly asking out of curiosity!

`

```
  const changeQuant =(dir)=>{
    let temp = total;

    switch(dir){

      case "plus":
        setQuantity(quantity+1)
        // (temp + price).toFixed(2);
         setTotal(total+price)
        break;

        case "minus":
          if(quantity === 0) return;
        setQuantity(quantity-1)
        (temp - price).toFixed(2);
        // setTotal(temp)
        break;

      default:
        console.log("unknown action!")
    }
  }
```

`

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] to your question? [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: add a semicolumn (`;`) after the setting of the state. Javascript is stupid and thinks your next line `(temp - price)` is part of the function above without it.

Comment: Also `toFixed` doesn't work in place. It returns the transformed value and returns a string.

Comment: See documentation for [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). If you want a `number` type (rounded to 2 decimal places) as a result of your subtraction operation, the correct syntax would be `const roundedDifferenceWithUpTo2Decimals = Number((numA - numB).toFixed(2))`.

Comment: Appreciate all the replies, to what was admittedly janky early morning snippet-ing. The `;` definitely appeared to be it, especially with how I was being sloppy with `toFixed()`.  Of course now in playing around with it, it'll work without but good knowing going fwd JS does sometimes see the `;` as something other than an indicator the programmer comes from another language. Also appreciate the insights on `toFixed()`, certainly helpful in realizing it returns a string. lol